# Is it possible to test for custom data-attributes in css-in-js?

Tags: javascript, css, custom-data-attribute, jss, css-in-js

I am trying to reference data attributes from JSS, test for them, and apply the styles if the test is true.  However, when I run the code below, it does not apply "color:green" and I have no idea why!

```
import React from "react";
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  statusDiv: {
    backgroundColor: "lightGrey",
    padding: "10px",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    '[data-status="OPEN"]': {
      // no effect ..?
      color: "green",
    },
  },
});

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div data-status="OPEN" className={classes.statusDiv}>
      OPEN
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting case.
What you can do is:

```
export default {
  '@global' : {
      'div.testClass[data-custom="value"]': {
      color: 'red',
      border: '1px, solid navy'
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes a JSS plug-in @global installed, but this is something I think is quite useful to have. 
More about the plug-in *@global* - [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-global?v=v10.1.1)

And if you want to address a **data-** attribute like in your edited example 0 you should do:

```
testClass: {
  '[data-custom="value"]': {
    //styles for the custom data
  }
}
```

And in the markup you'll have (depends on the way you extracting the class):

```
testClass.classes['[data-custom="value"]']
```

... styles for the custom data will be applied by the above.

The way you wrote in your last edit will not work. You should add a small bit though. To work the code example you provided:

```
...
fontWeight: "bold",
  '& [data-status="OPEN"]': {
  // no effect ..?
  color: "green",
},
```

The **&** require a nesting plug-in setup - [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.1.1) is more about it.

Comment: Thanks loads for the reply @Vladyn.. I've editted the post to include my most recent attempts based on your suggestion.. Not quite there yet, but I'm sure I'm missing something obvious (I'm not yet that familiar with JSS.) I have a suspicion I'm also doing things which are redundent..!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the amazing support from @Vladyn, the following code demonstrates this working perfectly :D

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "jss";
import { JssProvider, createUseStyles } from "react-jss";
import nested from "jss-plugin-nested";

const jss = create();
jss.use(nested());

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  statusDiv: {
    backgroundColor: "lightGrey",
    padding: "10px",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    '&[data-status="OPEN"]': {
      color: "green",
    },
    '&[data-status="CLOSED"]': {
      color: "red",
    },
  },
});

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const status = "OPEN";

  return (
    <JssProvider jss={jss}>
      <div data-status={status} className={classes.statusDiv}>
        {status}
      </div>
    </JssProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped @AdyBaby.

Comment: **MUI Note**: Looks like that if you use Material UI, you have to use `StylesProvider` from `@material-ui/core/styles` instead of JssProvider, otherwise you get an `Invalid prop jss of type Jss supplied to JssProvider` error.

Comment: If you have replaced MUI styles with `tss-react`, this should work out-of-the-box, without having to add the `jss-plugin-nested` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If your JS looks like this:

```js
<div data-customAttribute={value} className={classes.testClass}></div>
```

Your CSS will look like:

```css
.testClass[data-customAttribute="value"] {
  // your styles
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) The Q was more around specifically doing this using a CSS-in-JS approach though, like JSS.